# Android SQLite: Cannot insert more than one record

Tags: android, sqlite, auto-increment

I'm having trouble inserting more than one record into a SQLite Database. I already consulted the similiar questions, but I can't find the bug.

Here is a part of my CustomSQLiteHelper:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        final String CREATE_DATABASE_RESOURCE =
                "CREATE TABLE Resource("+
                        "_id            INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                        "timestamp      TEXT UNIQUE, " +
                        "title          TEXT, " + 
                        "description    TEXT, " + 
                        "latitude       TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
                        "longitude      TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
                        "altitude       TEXT NOT NULL);"; //+ 
                        //"PRIMARY KEY (_id, timestamp));";

        final String CREATE_DATABASE_IMAGE =
            "CREATE TABLE Image("+
                    "_id            INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    "timestamp      TEXT UNIQUE, " +
                    "timestampR     TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
                    "path           TEXT NOT NULL);";// +
                    //"PRIMARY KEY (_id, timestamp, timestampR), " +
                    //"FOREIGN KEY (timestampR) REFERENCES Resource (timestamp));";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_DATABASE_RESOURCE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_DATABASE_IMAGE);

    }

     public void insertResourceMetadata(String timestamp, String title, String desc, String lat, String lng, String alt){
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("timestamp", timestamp);
        values.put("title", title);
        values.put("description", desc);
        values.put("latitude", lat);
        values.put("longitude", lng);
        values.put("altitude", alt);

        database.insert("Resource", null, values);
        database.close();
    }

    public void insertImageMetadata(String timestamp, String timestampR, String path){
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues tempValues = new ContentValues();
        tempValues.put("timestamp", timestamp);
        tempValues.put("timestampR", timestampR);
        tempValues.put("path", path);

        database.insert("Image", null, tempValues);
        database.close();
    }
```

I have a scenario, in which the insertImageMetadata gets called three times inside a for loop, but inside the database is always only the first recorded entry (at all).

Comment: Are you sure that `timestamp` values are unique in these three rows you tried to insert?

Comment: yes, it is ensured from code, I also tested it by printing the single timestamps when calling the method.